# how to stop multiple re-renders from doing multiple api calls useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm new to react functional components and I'm trying to get the weather data on multiple cities on page load but useEffect is now re-rending each call. How can I write this so useEffect doesn't cause re-renders?

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [activeWeather, setActiveWeather] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

        const fetchData = async (city) => {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}`);
            setData((data) => [
                ...data,
                { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, country: res.data.sys.country, id: res.data.id },
            ]);
        };
        const fetchCities = () => {
            const cities = [fetchData("Ottawa"), fetchData("Toronto"), fetchData("Vancouver"), fetchData("California"), fetchData("London")];

            Promise.all(cities).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        };
        fetchCities();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the `fetchData` function to return the data you need without updating the state, then you can fetch x amount of cities and only when all of the requests complete update the state.

Note that if one of the requests inside [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) fail, it will go to the `catch` block without returning any data back, basically all or nothing

```js
const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

const fetchCity = async city => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}`,
  )

  return {
    description: data.weather[0].description,
    icon: data.weather[0].icon,
    temp: data.main.temp,
    city: data.name,
    country: data.sys.country,
    id: data.id,
  }
}

function App() {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([])
  const [activeWeather, setActiveWeather] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCities = async () => {
      const citiesData = await Promise.all(
        ['Ottawa', 'Toronto', 'Vancouver'].map(fetchCity),
      )

      setCities(prevState => prevState.concat(citiesData))
    }

    fetchCities()
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer overall! Side note: You're right ofc about the all-or-nothing aspect (can use `allSettled` to get more fine-grained info), but re *"...it will go to the catch block without resolving any of the promises..."* `Promise.all` doesn't *resolve* any promises other than its own, the promises will settle regardless of what `Promise.all` does. All `Promise.all` does is observe the results and either fulfill or reject its own promise. (Re "settle" vs. "fulfill" vs. "resolve", I [did a blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes great points, will update the answer. (and read the post on the way)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise.all` and then call `setData` once. something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchCity = (city) => axios.get(`${base}/${city}`);
  const cities = ["Ottawa", "Toronto"];
  const promises = cities.map(fetchCity);
  Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => {
    setData(cities.map((city, index) => ({ city, ...responses[index] })));
  });
}, []);
```